# How does the number many library in an R script impact on the performance?

Tags: r, performance, optimization, package

First of all, does using libraries has anything to do with the performance at all?
If yes, how big is the impact on the performance?

**Context**: I noticed that different packages are containing (very) similar functions. I can basically do many things with just one library, but I can also import different libraries to do the same task. I am asking this question because I would like to know if having several packages versus having few ones has an impact on the performance, so that I would know if I should care about optimizing my library or not.

```
library(syuzhet)
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library("rjson")
library(compare)
...
```

Comment: This question is too broad. There could be any differences in performance you can imagine. Let's think about a simple example: sort-libA and sort-libB. While both may sort your data, A will use mergesort and B will use bubblesort. Most of the time you would pay a high price for using B. Using many different libraries can pay off, if there are highly specialized algorithmic approaches for your problem. But you need to check the docs carefully!

Comment: The more `library` calls the more `.onLoad`/`.onAttach` calls and if the namespaces are large enough and the initialization code in load/attach is hefty enough you'll have an _initial hit_ on performance. After that, any performance issue is likely to be poorly written code on your part or using an unoptimized function in one of those libraries. I use _alot_ of packages in my daily work w/o no ill effect. You shld prbly focus more on your own code's performance.